# PHP Google Oauth API not setting token

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I'm having trouble with the Google API, but I'm also brand new to playing around with their API, so I'm needing some help. From what I'm gathering, the $client->getAccessToken is not being set properly. Can someone please help me figure out why the error message keeps reading inside of the gradebook.php? Why will the token not take?

Gradebook.php:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once 'oauth.php';

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    //Now have offline access of the user
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    //User token google drive call:
    $service = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);
    $courses = $service->courses->listCourses(['teacherId' => 'me']);

    foreach ($courses as $key => $course) {
        // var_dump($course->id);
        $courseWorks = $service->courses_courseWork->listCoursesCourseWork($course['id']);
        foreach ($courseWorks as $k => $courseWork) {
            // print_r($courseWork);
            // var_dump($courseWork->id);
            $studentSubmissions = $service->courses_courseWork_studentSubmissions->listCoursesCourseWorkStudentSubmissions($course->id, $courseWork->id);
            // print_r($studentSubmissions);
            foreach ($studentSubmissions as $i => $studentSubmission) {
                $student = $service->courses_students->get($course->id, $studentSubmission->userId);
                $emailAddress  = $student->getProfile()->emailAddress;
                $emailId = explode('@', $emailAddress)[0];

                var_dump($emailId);
                var_dump($course->id);
                var_dump($courseWork->id);
                var_dump($studentSubmission->assignedGrade);
            }
        }
    }
}

else {echo "ERROR DETECTED!!";}
```

Oauth.php:

```
session_start();
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

// initation configuration, as specificed by Google
$clientID = '(redacted)';
$clientSecret = '(redacted)';
$redirectUri = '(redacted)';

// create Client Request to access Google API
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($clientID);
$client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
$client->setScopes(array(
    "email",
    "profile",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos"
));

// establish session define_syslog_variables
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
```

Answer (score 1):

The access token needs to be set first before attempting to access a resource. I have adjusted your code to set the token.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../Internal/oauth.google.php';

$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION["token"]); //set the access token is what you missed

/*$client->getAccessToken() should return a none NULL value if set properly, something we have added above*/
if ($client->getAccessToken() !==NULL) { 
    //Now have offline access of the user
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    //User token google drive call:
    $service = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);
    $courses = $service->courses->listCourses(['teacherId' => 'me']);

    foreach ($courses as $key => $course) {
        print_r($course);
        $courseWorks = $service->courses_courseWork->listCoursesCourseWork($course['id']);
        foreach ($courseWorks as $k => $courseWork) {
            // print_r($courseWork);
            // var_dump($courseWork->id);
            $studentSubmissions = $service->courses_courseWork_studentSubmissions->listCoursesCourseWorkStudentSubmissions($course->id, $courseWork->id);
            // print_r($studentSubmissions);
            foreach ($studentSubmissions as $i => $studentSubmission) {
                $student = $service->courses_students->get($course->id, $studentSubmission->userId);
                $emailAddress  = $student->getProfile()->emailAddress;
                $emailId = explode('@', $emailAddress)[0];

                var_dump($emailId);
                var_dump($course->id);
                var_dump($courseWork->id);
                var_dump($studentSubmission->assignedGrade);
            }
        }
    }
}
else {header('Location: ../index.php'); exit();}
```